# Display data from MySQL database using PHP & HTML Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm a beginner in PHP. I want to Select and Display data from a MySQL database using PHP and HTML page.

I want both the PHP and the HTML files to be separated, because i will be using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap, and Phonegap doesn't support PHP files, so i have to put the PHP file in a webserver.

I'v already tried to look for a tutorial, but literally every tutorial on the internet shows how to do it all in a single PHP page.

Here is my code, which works fine, but its in a single .PHP file:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> Display Data </title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Email </th>
        </tr>
<?php
    //Create Connection with MySQL Database
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345');

    //Select Database
    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'profiles'))
    {
        echo "Database Not Selected";
    }
    //Select Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

    //Execute the SQL query
    $records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
    }
?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You're looking for a technique called ajax.

Comment: If you use jquery mobile, have a look at [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something along these lines. Remember that the getemployees.php file must generate an output in a format which can be directly injected in the div to look like a table in your case. Otherwise, you can rely on JSON response and then loop through the JSON data records and generate the output on client side.

**HTML File:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Display Data </title>
        <script>
          function getEmployees() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getemployees.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();

         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="txtHint"></div>
        <script>getEmployees();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            //Create Connection with MySQL Database
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345');

            //Select Database
            if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'profiles'))
            {
                echo "Database Not Selected";
            }
            //Select Query
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

            //Execute the SQL query
            $records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID </th>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Email </th>
                </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP has tagged jQuery mobile, so jQuery will most likely be available. `$("#txtHint").load( "getemployees.php" );` is quite a bit easier :-)